# debug or read code of System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent

Tags: asp.net, .net

is it possible to debut System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent or at least read code which is inside?

I have    Invalid postback or callback argument. The case is that I have test.mydomain.com. There is a cookie in domain .mydomain.com. When I delete this cookie there is no error but with this cookie error arrises :/

Thats why I wanted to debug the code that raises this exception but have no idea how :/

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in two ways.

1. Use [IlSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to open and decompile System.web.dll
   [image]
2. Use the [Microsoft reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/ClientScriptManager.cs,9c32722f6322eb9f)

If you start debugging you might consider setting the following options to enable stepping through the reference source:

In Debugging Options\General

- Unmark Just my code
- Mark Enable .Net Framework source steppig
- Mark Enable Source server support
- Unmark Require sourcefiles to exactly match the original version.

Comment: I tried to use IISPy but what I get is empty method:/ http://imageshack.com/a/img661/2566/iNAX1n.jpg

Comment: also when I try to get into code from visual studio I get this: http://imageshack.com/a/img674/1066/wnsUzu.jpg

Comment: Open up system.web.dll from the Framework folder. My screenshot is from this assembly: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll

Comment: Ok and maybe any tips on how to enable debugging in visual studio cause as I said before there is no source code available for this module :/

Comment: You clicked the Help in the refensource link and followed the debugging setup (much like I did here)?

Comment: Yeah, just dont know how to double check if I Validate that your Symbol path has no cached symbols